# Plotting the frequency bandwidth

Tags: pgfplots, intersections

I do not have almost any experience with `pgfplot` and I am having some problems with something which seemed really easy.

What I want to do is filling the area between a function and two vertical lines identified by the intersection of a horizontal line with the function.

I found the intersections and I could draw correctly the vertical lines but I cannot understand how to fill the area

Following there is the code I managed to produce so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}






\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=1]
\addplot+[name path global=GraphCurve, domain=0.5:1.5, samples=400, color=black, mark=none]{0.09*x^2/sqrt((1-x^2)^2+(0.09*x)^2)};

\addplot+[name path global=HorizontalLine, domain=0.5:1.5,mark=none, opacity=0]{0.5};

\path[dashed,name intersections={of=GraphCurve and HorizontalLine,name=i}] (i-2)%
      \pgfextra{\pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}%
         \global\let\macrox\macrox};
         \def \xinta {\macrox}
 \draw[name path global=vert1, dashed](i-2) -- (\xinta,0);        
 \path (i-1)
         \pgfextra{\pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy}%
         \global\let\macrox\macrox};
              \def \xintb {\macrox} 

\draw[name path global=vert2,dashed](i-1) -- (\xintb,0);
\coordinate [label=left:$A$](A) at (i-1);
\coordinate [label=right:$B$](B) at (i-2);


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This picture has been created with Pgfplots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Either TikZ CVS version or `pgfplots` 1.8 has issues with `name path global`. It doesn't recognize the names on my MikTeX machine. I'll try to check it again later.

Comment: @percusse It seems that in the definition of `\tikz@intersect@def`, the switching from `\let`s to `\def`s is the culprit. Changing it back, and the example works again.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah great. I should learn to diff better. I missed that. Do you mind filing a bug report for that?

Answer (score 5):

I’d clip it.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[name path global=GraphCurve, domain=0.5:1.5, samples=400, color=black, mark=none]{0.09*x^2/sqrt((1-x^2)^2+(0.09*x)^2)};

\addplot+[name path global=HorizontalLine, domain=0.5:1.5,mark=none, opacity=0]{0.5};

\path [name intersections={of=GraphCurve and HorizontalLine,name=i}];

\draw[dashed] (i-1) coordinate[label=left:$A$] -- ({axis cs:0,0} -| i-1);
\draw[dashed] (i-2) coordinate[label=right:$B$] -- ({axis cs:0,0} -| i-2);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \clip ({axis cs:0,0} -| i-1) rectangle ({axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}} -| i-2);
    \addplot+ [domain=0.5:1.5, samples=400, draw=none, mark=none, fill=gray] {0.09*x^2/sqrt((1-x^2)^2+(0.09*x)^2)} \closedcycle;
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]